# How can I group the shop names which have location number behind?

Tags: nlp, text-mining

I have a list of shop names which looks like this:

```
Mcdonald 54875
Mcdonald 654788
Mcdonald 5478654
124 Mcdonald 748415
Mcdonald 12213
34# ABC CHICKEN 45645
4A ABC CHICKEN 5464564
ABC CHICKEN 3474#99
ABC CHICKEN '#455
ABC CHICKEN #7885
etc.
```

I want to create a column to match the restaurant name like this

```
Mcdonald
Mcdonald
Mcdonald
Mcdonald
Mcdonald
ABC CHICKEN
ABC CHICKEN
ABC CHICKEN
ABC CHICKEN
ABC CHICKEN
etc.
```

Is there any possible way to do this automatically? Surely I cannot get all the main name I want. The list is too long

Comment: How do you know what is the name of restaurant? You have some predefined list or you just want to strip the numbers?

Comment: I don't have the predefined list and some of them contain not only number but characters too. Is there any possible way to guess the main name like the frequency?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression. For example:

```
s = """Mcdonald 54875
Mcdonald 654788
Mcdonald 5478654
124 Mcdonald 748415
Mcdonald 12213
34# ABC CHICKEN 45645
4A ABC CHICKEN 5464564
ABC CHICKEN 3474#99
ABC CHICKEN '#455
ABC CHICKEN #7885"""

import re
ans = []
re1=re.compile("(?<![0-9])[a-zA-Z]+")
for l in s.split('\n'):
    res = re1.findall(l)
    ans.append(" ".join(res))

for a in ans:
    print(a)
```

output:

> Mcdonald
>   Mcdonald
>   Mcdonald
>   Mcdonald
>   Mcdonald
>   ABC CHICKEN
>   ABC CHICKEN
>   ABC CHICKEN
>   ABC CHICKEN
>   ABC CHICKEN

Comment: what if some of the names contain characters? such as, Mcdonald qste, Mcdonald qstc. ABC CHICKEN a01, ABC CHICKEN a02, ABC CHICKEN rff? Does it still work?